# --ng build --env=prod is not working

Tags: angular

I am using angular4(4.4.6) and CLI 1.4.3.
I tried to make environment variables like in this article:
https://alligator.io/angular/environment-variables/

I ended up with 3 files:
**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  restUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  socketUrl: 'http://localhost:2000'
};
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  restUrl: 'http://139.130.4.5:3000/',
  socketUrl: 'http://139.130.4.5:2000'
};
```

and **environment.staging.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  restUrl: 'http://139.130.4.5:3000/',
  socketUrl: 'http://139.130.4.5:2000'
};
```

I use them as follows:

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
 constructor() {
    this.serverUrl = environment.restUrl;
    console.log('the env is:' this.serverUrl');
  }
```

and in **.angular-cli.json** I have the following:

```
"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
        "staging": "environments/environment.staging.ts"
      }
```

and from some reason, when I run `ng build --env=prod` it compiles and everything, but the final product uses the localHost(dev) enviorment variables.

whats even more strange is that when I use `ng server --env=prod` it works perfectly, with production variables.

why is this happening? how can I build with prod or staging environment variables?

Comment: @ Efim, I am facing the same issue with Angular 5, none of the below solution worked for me :(, Got any solution for ver 5 ?

Comment: @Efim, Did you ever find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 56):

Use command like this for Anuglar 6 to build

```
ng build --prod --configuration=dev
```

Or using alias:

```
ng build --prod --c=dev
```

Comment: this doesn't target the environment file, rather the configuration entry in angular.json file

Comment: Serves the same purpose though. You'd have to add file replacements in the `angular.json` config file (which should just be created automatically when you migrate to Angular 6).

Answer (score 20):

Angular 7+ (8/9/10) - via CLI created project:

`ng build --prod --configuration production`

Answer (score 9):

Try setting your target environment too like so:

`ng build --target=production --environment=prod`
or
`ng build --prod --env=prod`
or
`ng build --prod`

per https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build development target is used by default.

Comment: The thing is, I am not ready for production YET,
Angular is unsatisfied with useless files(which would be used in the future).

Answer (score 6):

This was an old issue that was fixed in newer versions of the cli. I can't tell though if this is it without knowing what cli and @angular minor and patch versions you are using.

Try adding `./` to your .`angular-cli.json` envs.

```
"environments": {
    "dev": "./environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "./environments/environment.prod.ts",
    "staging": "./environments/environment.staging.ts"
}
```

If this fixes it for you then I recommend that you upgrade your dependencies and your cli to the latest version and your angular packages to the latest 4.minor.patch versions to prevent running into other already fixed bugs.

Comment: the './' fix didn't work, I use Angular 4.4.6,
and CLI 1.4.3

Answer (score 4):

You can add file replacements for specific build targets in `angular.json`

##### Production

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    ],
```

Run `ng build --configuration=production`, and the src/environments/environment.ts file is replaced with the target-specific version of the file, src/environments/environment.prod.ts.

##### Staging

```
"configurations": {
  "production": { … },
  "staging": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

To build using the staging configuration, run the following command:

`ng build --configuration=staging`

You can also add the `defaultConfiguration` in `build`

```
 "build": {
    "configurations": {.......},
    "defaultConfiguration": "staging"

}
```

When you run `ng build`, the building target is `staging`

Comment: Thanks. Above works with version of Angular: 15.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the imports are correct in your respective components. Importing the wrong environment file by mistake could cause this issue as well. In my case I had the import like this:

```
import { environment } from '../../../../environment/environment.dev';
```

This confused a lot of us until we found it out as we never looked at the imports. We must import the environment.ts file only then only it can use the replaced file. The corrected import will look like this:

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the below command

`ng build -prod`